How do i start coding other pages in flutter after the main.dart page?
I want to start coding the onProgress page which is the first page on my app which the user see after opening my app.
I've tried doing it like this, but am not sure if the syntax start like this
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OnBoard extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnBoard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text("Welocome to My App"));
  }
}


Using Scaffold provides a standard app layout with an AppBar, body, and other essential elements. It helps structure your screen, ensures consistency, and makes it easier to add features like buttons, drawers, or snack bars.
If you need to more suggestion for this then prefer this link
void main() {
      runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: OnBoard(),
      ));
    }


class OnBoard extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnBoard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Welcome'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          "Welcome to My App",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Code is almost correct for creating a simple page in Flutter. Here are a few points to improve and ensure it works:
Scaffold: Wrap your Center widget in a Scaffold. This provides a basic structure for your app, like app bars or floating action buttons.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Text("Welcome to My App"),
    ),
  );
}

MaterialApp: If this is the first page of your app, you need to run it inside a MaterialApp in the main.dart file.
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: OnBoard(),
  ));
}

Fix Typo: There's a typo in your text. It should be "Welcome" instead of "Welocome."
With these changes, your app will display the "Welcome to My App" text properly when it starts.
Keep coding—you’re on the right track!
